# Is there a way to build native plugins for trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

I am interested in writing native plugins for trigger.io.
Is this already possible or on the roadmap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's definitely on the roadmap: the main reason we didn't allow this from day one is that our main initial focus has been creating a development cycle which is as smooth and rapid as possible.

We're approaching the point where we - and our users - are pretty happy with the tooling, and it will be time to evaluate the best way to allow for native plugins.

Our primary goal will always be to make mobile development as easy as web development, so I won't allow native plugins to degrade the experience for users not interested in them. However, we do realise they are an important tool, and we're looking forward to extend our platform to allow them.

**Update**: we've launched a beta of custom plugins for Forge - see http://current-docs.trigger.io/modules/native/index.html

Comment: Hey guys, any idea of timeline? I really want to use trigger.io for an app I am making at the moment, but need to use the native share intents in android.

Comment: Hi, we're still looking at this on a medium-term basis: we've a bunch of new features we need to nail and deploy first. As things stand it's the next Big Thing after those are done. Don't hold me to it, but I'd estimate fall for a preview release.

Comment: I'm also very interested in writing native plugins for trigger.io, since we would like to use several things, which work with phonegap, but not trigger.io, yet :-)